# Sending parameters to a DLL to be boost::bind'ed

Tags: c++, dll, boost, bind

I have a DLL which has a function which accepts a function pointer converts it to a boost::function. This is then stored and then called from inside the DLL.

I want to add a function to the DLL to handle member functions in a similar way. I know I need to use boost::bind to wrap the member function pointer and the object together. I want to do the binding on the DLL side though so the EXE does not require boost libraries to be included.

How would you write this function? One which accepts a member function pointer and an object as arguments and binds them together.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use `boost::bind` within the DLL?

Comment: I want to use boost bind I'm just not sure how to pass what is required to do the binding from the exe to the dll

Comment: Post some sample code demonstrating your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're warned by @Kylotan, so you can try something like this:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void store_mem_fn(void(Your_class::*mem_fn)(void), Your_class& instance)
{
    std::vector<boost::function<void(void)> > container;
    container.push_back(boost::bind(mem_fn, instance));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bad idea to try passing member function pointers into DLLs because they can vary in size depending on certain circumstances. (Some details [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040209-00/?p=40713).) Maybe if you always know that you will be building both halves of the application with the same compiler you will be ok.

As for the function, I expect it would look something like this (completely untested and uncompiled code):

```
typedef void(ObjectType::*OTMemberFn)();

boost::function<void (ObjectType o)> bind_mem_fn(ObjectType o, OTMemberFn mf)
{
    return boost::bind(mf, o);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't Boost open source? If so, peek into the boost code, learn how it's done, and re-implement it yourself, without the dependency.